# Text generated by php to span

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have function (PHP) which generates some text, let say:

```
function A()
{
    echo 'test';
}
```

Next, I have (HTML):

```
<span id="content"></span>
```

Then, I have (JavaScript):

```
fillObjectContent = function(object, content)
{
    $(object).html(content);
}
```

And now, how can I put text from function A with this JS+jQuery function? (or another way). I mean in PHP using:

```
echo "<script>fillObjectContent('#content', 'test content')";
```

What should I put in the place of 'test content'?

Comment: Do you want to call the function after page is requested, by an user action? If yes, use Ajax, if no, call the function and concatenate the returned string.

Comment: It doesn't matter actually. The question is what can I put against 'test content' to execute function A (PHP) to my <span>

Comment: It's important to my to use echo, not return string

Comment: Well, your function returns a string and then you echo it.

Comment: This is the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to call the JavaScript `fillObjectContent` function and set the value of `#content` element using a returned/echoed value of a PHP function(after page is loaded), you can use Ajax:

```
var fillObjectContent = function(url, selector) {
   $.ajax({
       url, url, 
       type: 'GET',
   }).done(function(returnedData) {
      $(selector).html(returnedData);
   })
}

fillObjectContent('urlString', '#content');
```

Note that `echo`ing JavaScript codes is *hackish*, you can `json_encode` the value and store it in a JavaScript variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think You need this:

```
echo "<script>fillObjectContent('#content', '"; A(); echo "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
echo "<script>fillObjectContent('#content', '".A()."')";
```

This will print the contents of A() but instead of using this

```
function A() {
    echo 'test';
}
```

use this

```
function A() {
    $var = "Some text here";
    return $var;
}
```

This allows you to pass `variables` into is as well to swap out the $var value if you like by making it like so:

```
function A($string = null) {
    $var = "Some text here";
    if($string != null) {
        $var = $string;
    }
    return $var;
}
```

Now you can replace your string using any set text you want by calling it like `A("Hello World");` to return the value `Hello World`.